# Tool for monitoring and tracking JVM applications

Tags: java, scala

I want to monitor JVM applications.

I want something simple to set up, easy and intuitive.

I want insights about the bottle necks of my applications.

I have applications running on the JVM, and using Scala as it main language.

Most of them Using Play Framework and Hibernate.

I want monitor Memory, IO, Connection Pools, Locks, Processing.

Again, something visual and intuitive.

Comment: There are so many JVM monitoring tools, I have written several different ones myself. Please list everything you want to monitor (ex: locks, IO, database connection pools, etc). Also, what is your budget?

Comment: HI @NicolasRaoul, I want to monitor Connection Pools, Locks, Memory, IO.

Comment: Should it be gratis?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - No, it can be paid. If it is good we are willing to pay.

Comment: I once used http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/ but I'm not sure whether it fulfills your need.